# Angular 5 --prod --aot build issue with ngCli

Tags: angular, angular5

In My project ng build command executing successfully and running as well.

But when I build ng build --prod --aot, build is successful but not running.

Error: StaticInjectorError[n]: 
  StaticInjectorError[n]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for n!

Please help.

Comment: Did you create your project using 'ng new'?

Comment: Yes. but components are copied from existing angular 2 project.

Comment: It is possible that some components inject services which you correctly imported into the component file, but not the module.

Comment: i have injected common services in provider of app.module.ts and component specific services in provider of component. Is that correct or I have to inject all services in app.module.ts?

Comment: Actually providing services directly into components is not a good practice. My point is maybe you missed some service

Comment: Actually it's a huge project and I am migrating it from Angular 2 to Angular 5. It is really difficult to find which service causing this issue. if there is any way to figure value of "n", let me know.